# all svn command throws error Error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: ubuntu, svn

In ubuntu When i try to run any avn commands like svn up, svn info , svn st , it gives an error : Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 1):

Your svn client is crashing. Report a bug at [Ubuntus launchpad](https://launchpad.net/).